# Compiling pascal programs with FPC and then running them, all in Notepad++

Tags: compilation, notepad++, pascal

Here's my problem

I've been searching for a while now on how to compile a pascal program in notepad, then immediately running it after a successful compile.

So far, I've managed just to find a compile script for NppExec, which goes like this :

```
PATH_TO_FPC\ppc386.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

I've tried combining this script with another script for compiling and running C/C++ programs in notepad++

> cmd /K DPATH-TO-FPC\ppc386.exe
>   "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" -o
>   "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART).exe"

but I always get a message, when I try to run it.

> *"Error: Illegal parameter: -o"*

So I was wondering if anyone can help me with this, or post a complete solution if they know on a topic.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Might be easier to punch this into a seperate `.bat` file and just invoke that.

Comment: Still the same, any other suggestions ? :/

Comment: Use F9 in CodeTyphon/Lazarus/FreePascalIDE, unless you really want full control on your own. http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=96&catid=68&Itemid=147

Answer (score 0):

Try to append -o with your output executable file. Which will be like this:
-o"$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART).exe"